# Is it good practice to require associated Error types implement Debug trait?

Tags: rust

I've run into a problem with `piston2d-graphics` crate. When I try to use `expect()` method on `Result` that I get from `graphics::character::CharacterCache::character` method, it turns out I can't — because it requires the Error type of the Result to implement `std::fmt::Debug` trait:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `expect` found for type `std::result::Result<graphics::character::Character<'_, <G as graphics::Graphics>::Texture>, <C as graphics::character::CharacterCache>::Error>` in the current scope
  --> src/some_file.rs:44:53
   |
44 |             let ch_glyph = glyphs.character(34, ch).expect("Couldn't load character");
   |                                                     ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `expect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<C as graphics::character::CharacterCache>::Error : std::fmt::Debug`
```

`Error` here is an associated (nested) type in `CharacterCache` trait. I can easily submit a PR that adds the requirement and then add it's implementation with a simple derive macro to all other crates. It seems reasonable, because `expect()` and other related methods are used in Rust all the time, but I'm not sure. Is it the Rust way, or are there reasons not to do it?

---

I describe the question using example of it's occurrence, but it has nothing specific to do with Piston, my question is about general pattern in Rust. So tag `rust-piston` is unrelated, please don't add it to the question.

Comment: Adding `where <C as graphics::character::CharacterCache>::Error : std::fmt::Debug` on the function that calls `expect` (and possibly other functions that call the first one) should solve the problem too.

Comment: @FrancisGagné but then this function wouldn't be usable unless I actually fix the libraries I'm using, and this question is exactly about whether I should do it

Comment: Oh, I assumed the error types in question already implemented `Debug`. Nevermind then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it good practice to require associated Error types implement Debug trait?

Yes, when possible. Maybe they forget it.

A way to solve this problem is to use `map_err()`, here a MCVE of the problem:

```
struct Error;

fn foo() -> Result<(), Error> {
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    foo().expect("no error");
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `expect` found for type `std::result::Result<(), Error>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:11
  |
8 |     foo().expect("no error");
  |           ^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `expect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `Error : std::fmt::Debug`
```

Use `map_err()` to produce an error that implement Debug, that could be your own custom Error, In the following exemple, I just return `()` as Error:

```
struct Error;

fn foo() -> Result<(), Error> {
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    foo().map_err(|_| ()).expect("no error");
}
```